# Escrever TimeSpan por extenso

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor, timespan

Quero escrever uma classe estática (pode ser *Extension*) para representar o valor de uma estrutura [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) por extenso, em português.

A ideia é sempre comparar a data atual ([`Datetime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)) com a data que o evento ocorreu. O resultado disso é um `TimeSpan` que quero usar para escrever no Razor datas assim:

> Há 3 segundos.
>
> Há 2 horas.
>
> Há 2 dias e 5 horas.
>
> Há uma semana.
>
> Há 3 semanas e 2 dias.
>
> Há um mês.
>
> Há 3 meses, 2 semanas e 4 dias.
>
> Há um ano.
>
> Há 2 anos e 7 meses.

Como isso poderia ser feito de uma forma elegante?

Comment: A funcionalidade que procuras chama-se *relative time*. [Eis um ponto de partida](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11/857807).

Comment: Se precisar dá suporte a outros idiomas, pode pensar neste Nuget: [TimeAgo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeAgo/)

Comment: @TobyMosque Sensacional esse TimeAgo! Vou fazer uns testes com ele.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Há uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248/221800) que trata disto e foi bem aceita. Eu provavelmente melhoraria alguma coisa para ficar mais elegante e ainda não está fazendo exatamente como deseja, mas é isto:

```
public static String RelativeTime(this TimeSpan ts) {
    const int second = 1;
    const int minute = 60 * second;
    const int hour = 60 * minute;
    const int day = 24 * hour;
    const int month = 30 * day;
    double delta = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);
    //melhor se escrever só "Agora há pouco"
    if (delta < 1 * minute) return "Há " + (ts.Seconds == 1 ? "um segundo" : ts.Seconds + " segundos");
    if (delta < 2 * minute) return "Há um minuto";
    if (delta < 45 * minute) return "Há " + ts.Minutes + " minutos";
    if (delta < 90 * minute) return "Há uma hora";
    if (delta < 24 * hour) return "Há " + ts.Hours + " horas";
    if (delta < 48 * hour) return "ontem";
    if (delta < 30 * day) return "Há " + ts.Days + " dias";
    if (delta < 12 * month) {
        var months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
        return "Há " + (months <= 1 ? "um mês" : months + " meses");
    } else {
        var years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
        return "Há " + (years <= 1 ? "um ano" : years + " anos");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Udjmlo). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N2ebwR). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Humanize.cs).

Ele tem alguns problemas mas resolve a maioria das situações. Um dos problemas é que não trata se o valor for futuro. A calibragem do arredondamento está rígida, enfim, dá para fazer várias melhorias no algoritmo, além de melhorar o estilo do código.

Também tem esse [pacote que ajuda a "humanizar"](http://humanizr.net/) todos esses dados.

Tem uma alternativa que considera o tempo parcial conforme mostrado na pergunta. A implementação não leva em consideração alguns pequenos deslocamentos, plural, horas, etc., conforme informado na [resposta original no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1138852/221800):

```
var dtNow = DateTime.Now;
var dtYesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-435.0);
var ts = dtNow.Subtract(dtYesterday);
var years = ts.Days / 365; //no leap year accounting
var months = (ts.Days % 365) / 30; //naive guess at month size
var weeks = ((ts.Days % 365) % 30) / 7;
var days = (((ts.Days % 365) % 30) % 7);
var sb = new StringBuilder("Há ");
if(years > 0) sb.Append(years.ToString() + " anos, ");
if(months > 0) sb.Append(months.ToString() + " meses, ");
if(weeks > 0) sb.Append(weeks.ToString() + " semanas, ");
if(days > 0) sb.Append(days.ToString() + " dias.");
var FormattedTimeSpan = sb.ToString();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Humanize2.cs).

Comment: Eu posso melhorar. Talvez precise mudar a fonte de dados. Tem algo que precisa além de colocar as frações de tempo? Eu acho que usando isto recursivamente fica fácil já que você pode ir subtraindo o que já achou e ir pegando o resto do tempo que ainda não foi transformado para uma nova execução. Essa parece ser mais próxima: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1138852/221800 se atender melhor, posso adaptar e por na resposta.

Comment: Não precisa. Esta está ótima. Obrigado!

Answer (score 14):

Apenas a título de curiosidade, implementei a resposta do @Maniero como uma *Extension*, a seguir:

```
public static class RelativeTimeExtensions
{
    public static String PorExtenso(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        const int SECOND = 1;
        const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
        const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
        const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
        const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;

        // var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - yourDate.Ticks);
        double delta = Math.Abs(timeSpan.TotalSeconds);

        if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
        {
            return "Há " + (timeSpan.Seconds == 1 ? "um segundo" : timeSpan.Seconds + " segundos");
        }
        if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
        {
            return "Há um minuto";
        }
        if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
        {
            return "Há " + timeSpan.Minutes + " minutos";
        }
        if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
        {
            return "Há uma hora";
        }
        if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
        {
            return "Há " + timeSpan.Hours + " horas";
        }
        if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
        {
            return "ontem";
        }
        if (delta < 30 * DAY)
        {
            return "Há " + timeSpan.Days + " dias";
        }
        if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
        {
            int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)timeSpan.Days / 30));
            return "Há " + (months <= 1 ? "um mês" : months + " meses");
        }
        else
        {
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)timeSpan.Days / 365));
            return "Há " + (years <= 1 ? "um ano" : years + " anos");
        }
    }
}
```

Uso (no Razor):

```
@((DateTime.Now - dataDeComparacao).PorExtenso())
```

Answer (score 4):

Só para acrescentar mais conteúdo essa é a minha solução um pouco parecida, onde eu passo um `datetime` como parametro:

```
public static string TimeAgo(DateTime dt)
    {
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - dt;

        if (span.Days > 365)
        {
            int years = (span.Days / 365);

            if (span.Days % 365 != 0)
                years += 1;

            return String.Format("Há {0} {1} atrás",

            years, years == 1 ? "dia" : "dias");
        }
        if (span.Days > 30)
        {
            int months = (span.Days / 30);

            if (span.Days % 31 != 0)
                months += 1;

            return String.Format("Há {0} {1} atrás",

            months, months == 1 ? "mês" : "Mês");
        }
        if (span.Days > 0)
            return String.Format("Há {0} {1} Atrás",

            span.Days, span.Days == 1 ? "Dia" : "Dias");

        if (span.Hours > 0)
            return String.Format("Há {0} {1} Atrás",

            span.Hours, span.Hours == 1 ? "hora" : "horas");

        if (span.Minutes > 0)
            return String.Format("Há {0} {1} Atrás",

            span.Minutes, span.Minutes == 1 ? "minutos" : "minutos");

        if (span.Seconds > 5)
            return String.Format("Há {0} segundos atrás", span.Seconds);

        if (span.Seconds <= 5)
            return "agora";

        return string.Empty;
    }
```