# Como humanizar uma data em PHP

Tags: php, data

Como humanizar uma data em PHP? Por exemplo, a partir dessa data `2015-08-20`, quero que a função me retorne `Há uma semana`, pois é estranho ler algo como `foi publicado há 754 dias` ou `publicado há 38 semanas`.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82278/101

Comment: @bigown, valeu essa ai eu não conhecia

Answer (score 23):

Conheço duas bibliotecas para fazer essa conversão, uma é a [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) que é uma especialização da DateTime padrão do php e a [PHP Humanizer](https://github.com/coduo/php-humanizer) que humaniza datas
e outras informações a limitação dela hoje é que possui localização apenas para inglês e polonês.

### Carbon

Faça a instalação do nfs carbon pelo composer na linha de comando.

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

O criação do objeto pede uma data e o timezone ambos são opcionais, `setLocale()` é reponsavel pelas traduções sua chamada pode ser feita via 
método estatico e `diffForHumans()` retorna a string formatada de quanto tempo passou desde a data inicial.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;
$data = new Carbon('2015-08-20', 'America/Sao_Paulo');
$data->setLocale('pt_BR');
echo $data->diffForHumans() .PHP_EOL;

$data->addDays(3);
echo $data->diffForHumans() .PHP_EOL;
```

Saída:

```
há 1 semana
há 6 dias
```

### PHP Humanizer

Instalação

```
composer require coduo/php-humanizer
```

`difference()` faz o mesmo que `diffForHumans()` retorna uma string formatada aproximada, como `1 week ago`, `preciseDifference()` exibe a diferença completa algo como:
`20 days, 16 minutes, 52 seconds from now`

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Coduo\PHPHumanizer\DateTime;

$data = new \DateTime('2015-08-10');
echo DateTime::difference($data, new \DateTime()) .PHP_EOL;
echo DateTime::preciseDifference($data, new \DateTime()) .PHP_EOL;
```

Saída:

```
3 weeks from now
20 days, 18 minutes, 7 seconds from now
```

Answer (score 14):

Seguindo o mesmo princípio [desta postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82278/70), pode partir deste código:

```
function RelativeTimeString($timestamp) {
    $minute = 60;
    $hour = $minute * 60;
    $day = $hour * 24;
    $month = 30 * $day;
    $year = 12 * $month;

    $delta = floor(time() - $timestamp);
    if ($delta < 2 )           return 'Agorinha';
    if ($delta < 1 * $minute)  return "Há $delta segundos";
    if ($delta < 2 * $minute)  return 'Há um minuto';
    if ($delta < 45 * $minute) return 'Há '.round($delta / $minute).' minutos';
    if ($delta < 90 * $minute) return 'Há uma hora';
    if ($delta < 23 * $hour)   return 'Há '.round($delta / $hour).' horas';
    if ($delta < 48 * $hour)   return 'Ontem';
    if ($delta < 30 * $day)    return 'Há '.round($delta / $day).' dias';
    if ($delta < 45 * $day)    return 'Há um mês';
    if ($delta < 11 * $month)  return 'Há '.round($delta / $month).' meses';
    if ($delta < 18 * $month)  return 'Há um ano';
    return 'Há '.round($delta / $year).' anos';
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/pMZvsw)**

#### Notas:

- Por uma questão de conveniência, mantive o parâmetro como timestamp (em segundos, mais fácil de adaptar pra qualquer linguagem ou implementação). Para entrar com a data em string, basta usar

  ```
  strtotime( $DateString )
  ```

  em vez de

  ```
  $timestamp
  ```

  lembrando que datas com `/` são consideradas `MM/DD/AAAA` e com `-` são consideradas `DD-MM-AAAA`. Datas em `AAAA-MM-DD` são entendidas corretamente com qualquer separador.
- O `time()` é baseado em UTC, se seus dados estiverem salvos em hora local (o que pode não ser interessante para este tipo de aplicação), precisa acrescentar a diferença:

  ```
  $tzseconds = date('Z');
  $delta = floor(time() - $timestamp - $tzseconds);
  ```
- Considere que se tiver intervalos maiores que a capacidade de inteiros do PHP, precisa revisar a aplicação, pois inteiros de 32 bits só cobrem um *span* de 68 anos. Esta não é uma limitação da função em si, mas sim do modo com que inteiros são armazenados no PHP.