# Formatação de campo TIME

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho o seguinte dado no banco `55:42:55` e preciso deixa-lo mais legível desta forma `2d7h42m` como eu poderia fazer essa formatação?

Comment: Fundamental [edit] a pergunta e explicar qual o tipo do campo usado, faz diferença neste caso. O normal seria um campo de tempo ou numérico, e a formatação ser feita na linguagem cliente, se houver, e não no SQL. Se for string, já precisa converter.

Comment: Seria [isso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83326/91) ?

Comment: @rray não exatamente...

Comment: @Bacco bem, esse resultado é uma conversão de segundos com SEC_TO_TIME então provavelmente o campo é um varchar... No caso se houvesse uma forma de humanizar segundos diretamente para este formato `%Dd %Hh %Mm` também resolveria

Comment: @rray seu exemplo é especifico pra php, eu preciso que o resultado saia pré-formatado do banco.