# Erro "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare (previously declared)"

Tags: php

Tenho um botão de notificação, onde o mesmo mostra os últimos pedidos que sairão no sistema, queria adicionar o tempo que ele já saiu. Ex.: 4 minutos atrás, 1 hora atrás, e quando fosse acima de 24 horas ele mostrasse 1 dias atrás, 2 dias atrás..... Tentei de varias formas diminuir os horários, mas não consegue. Em meu banco de dados guardo os seguintes dados:

> data_registro -> o dia que foi registrado Ex.: 2017-05-18;
>
> horario_registro- > a hora que foi registrado Ex.: 10:19:30

```
function tempoCorridoDois($dataHoraString2) {
    $hoje2 = strtotime(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'));
    $dataHora2 = strtotime($dataHoraString2);
    $diferenca2 = $hoje2 - $dataHora2;

    $segundos2 = $diferenca2;
    $minutos2 = round($diferenca2 / 60);
    $horas2 = round($diferenca2 / 3600);
    $dias2 = round($diferenca2 / 86400);
    $semanas2 = round($diferenca2 / 604800);
    $meses2 = round($diferenca2 / 2419200);
    $anos2 = round($diferenca2 / 29030400);

    if ($segundos2 <= 60) {
      return "1 minuto atrás.";
    }else if ($minutos2 <= 60) {
      return  $minutos2 . ' minutos atrás.';
      }else if ($horas2 <= 24) {
        return $horas2 . ' horas atrás.';
        }else if ($dias2 <= 7) {
          return $dias2 . ' dia(s) atrás.';
          }else if ($semanas2 <= 4) {
            return $semanas2 . ' semanas atrás.';
            }else if ($meses2 <= 12) {
              return $meses2 . ' meses atrás.';
              }else{
                return $anos2 . ' anos atrás.';
              }
  }
      $tempoFinal2 = tempoCorridoDois($dataregistro2.$horarioregistro2);
```

> E aparece o seguinte erro:
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare tempoCorridoDois() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\pedidos\componentes\php\ff_notificacao_php.php:136) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pedidos\componentes\php\ff_notificacao_php.php on line 136

Comment: Você está salvando a data no banco nesse formato?

Comment: Já corrigido @LucasThibauPaulino

Comment: Bom, você pode usar o date_diff() (ex: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp) ou tratar a data e a hora como string, separando ela em blocos e fazendo o cálculo manual. Ambas as formas funcionam, só muito cuidado no momento de tratar essas informações, qualquer errinho faz tudo parar de funcionar.

Comment: A edição invalidava uma resposta e de qualquer forma já existe uma pergunta sobre o assunto em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83326/3635 com duas respostas, não há necessidade de mais. Se tiver alguma duvida extra além do problema especifico de comparar duas datas então recomendo criar uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a [função date_diff()](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-diff.php) ou fazer manualmente igual mostro abaixo:

```
 function tempoCorrido($dataHoraString) {
    $hoje = time();
    $dataHora = strtotime($dataHoraString);
    $diferenca = $hoje - $dataHora;

    $segundos = $diferenca;
    $minutos = round($diferenca / 60);
    $horas = round($diferenca / 3600);
    $dias = round($diferenca / 86400);
    $semanas = round($diferenca / 604800);
    $meses = round($diferenca / 2419200);
    $anos = round($diferenca / 29030400);

    if ($segundos <= 60) {
        return $segundos . " segundos atrás";
    } 
    else if ($minutos <= 60) {
        return  $minutos . 'min atrás';
    } 
    else if ($horas <= 24) {
        return $horas . ' hrs atrás';
    } 
    else if ($dias <= 7) {
        return $dias . ' dias atrás';
    } 
    else if ($semanas <= 4) {
        return $semanas . ' semanas atrás';
    } 
    else if ($meses <= 12) {
        return $meses . ' meses atrás';
    } 
    else {
        return $anos . ' anos atrás';
    }
}

echo tempoCorrido("2017-05-18 10:40:00");
```

Comment: Diego de uma olhada no meu código estou com problemas, minha pergunta esta editada.

Comment: Você declarou uma função com o nome tempoCorridoDois no arquivo ff_notificacao_php e também declarou essa função no arquivo que vc está executando. Não pode ter duas funções com mesmo nome.

Comment: pq só dá como resultado 1 minuto?

Comment: Diego deu certo agradeço muito

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo
 
A condição $segundos <= 60 estava fixo para exibir 1 minuto. Fiz o ajuste para exibir em segundos.

Comment: Diego e @GabrielFilippi Uma dica, troque `$hoje = strtotime(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'));` por `$hoje = time();`, usar `strtotime(date('Y/m/d H:i:s'))` é bastante redundante

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 6):

O erro:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare tempoCorridoDois() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\pedidos\componentes\php\ff_notificacao_php.php:136) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pedidos\componentes\php\ff_notificacao_php.php on line 136

Indica que a função foi declarada duas vezes, ou você realmenete declarou duas vezes ou você deve estar usando o `include` (ou `require`) mais de uma vez em arquivos diferentes

**Para resolver** troque `require` ou `include` por `require_once` ou `include_once`, se não for este o problema então revise teus scripts deve haver realmente duas funções com mesmo nome.

Sobre "humanizar as horas", recomendo você experimentar as soluções apresentadas em:

- [Como humanizar uma data em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83326/3635)