# Subtração de data hoje - data inicial no PHP e trazer resultado ex: 1 dia 5hs e 25min

Tags: php, datetime

Tenho 2 variáveis em PHP. A primeira é a data do pedido $datapedido e a segunda é a data de agora $agora. Preciso listar há quanto tempo o pedido está aberto.

O $datapedido é consultado em MYSQL.

Ambos são no mesmo formato: ('Y-m-d H:i').

Queria, em php, fazer uma conta de $agora - $datapedido e ter um resultado, por exemplo, de 1 dia, 5hs e 25min, se possível, já fazer isso na consulta do mysql para eu conseguir ordenar pelo que está a mais tempo aberto.

Comment: Já tem uma resposta sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas/70

Comment: A resposta do @Bacco parece uma boa sugestão que vai além do mysql: **[Como humanizar uma data em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195690/3635)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tabela utilizada**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Consulta realizada dia 31/08 as 21:29hs do servidor**

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,NOME_COLUNA,now()) , ' dias ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,NOME_COLUNA,now()), 24), ' hs ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,NOME_COLUNA,now()), 60), ' min '
) from NOME_TABELA
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- CONCAT função para unir valores da consulta
- TIMESTAMPDIFF - função para calcular a diferença entre datas

### Ordenação da consulta

> Para campos alfanuméricos 10 vem antes de a 2 porque a avaliação é feita da esquerda para a direita digito a digito.

Tabela utilizada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:

[image: reult asc]

Com valores numéricos a ordenação padrão é dos mais baixos para os mais elevados, exceto se for especificado `DESC` em order by

**Para ordenar o resultado**, já que é sempre iniciado por um numero, pode converter o resultado da consulta em numero que o sql vai capturar a parte antes das letras e converter para um número, ordenando então o resultado por este valor.

Consulta:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,NOME_COLUNA,now()) , ' dias ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,NOME_COLUNA,now()), 24), ' hs ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,NOME_COLUNA,now()), 60), ' min '
) as resultado from NOME_TABELA ORDER BY CAST(resultado AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

[image: ordenada]

Comment: Só uma coisa, eu ordenei e ele entende que 10 dias é menor que 2 dias (a ordem fica 1, 10, 14, 2). Como faço pra colocar na ordem certa? (1,2,10,14)

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo, você pode converter o resultado da consulta em numero que o sql vai capturar a parte antes das letras e converter para um número, ordenando então o resultado por este valor. Veja resposta editada.