# tratar data e hora php

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de posts, onde no rodapé de cada um é exibido o momento em que o post foi publicado. Para isso, eu uso o `diff` para calcular a diferença entre a data atual e a data em que o post foi publicado.

Eu quero que, quando um post tiver menos de uma hora de diferença, ele retorne pra min apenas os minutos, por exemplo:

- no banco de dados a data em que o post foi pulicado é salva como: (*2018-01-10 16:02:17*)
- agora são: *2018-01-10 16:05:17*
- o retorno seria: *2018-01-10 00:03:00*, isto é, 3 minutos de diferença

mas eu quero que nesse caso, ele retorne pra mim apenas os minutos, pois as horas e os segundos são 00, e que a mesma coisa aconteça com as horas, se for maior que 00, isto é mais de 1 hora de diferença, ele retorne apenas as horas, no caso 01.

Eu tentei esse código aqui mas falhou, não retorna nada.

```
function DateTime($date){
    $dated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data1 = new DateTime( $dated );
    $data2 = new DateTime( $date );

    $intervalo = $data1->diff( $data2 );

    if (($intervalo->h) == "0") {
        return $intervalo->i ." Minutos atrás";
    }else{
        return $intervalo->h ." Horas atrás";
    }

    if (($intervalo->i) == "0") {
        return "Agora mesmo";
    }

}
```

Comment: Seria isso? [Como humanizar uma data em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83326/91)

Comment: Uma api herdada do php http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-introduction é muito boa para fazer tratamento de datas e horas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fox vê se é isso que você quer código:

```
function cal_data($date1, $date2){

$dateS1 = new \DateTime($date1);
$dateS2 = new \DateTime($date2);

$dateDiff = $dateS1->diff($dateS2);

if ($dateDiff->h == 0) {
  $result = $dateDiff->i . ' minutos';
} else {
  $result = $dateDiff->h . ' horas e ' . $dateDiff->i . ' minutos';
}

echo $result;

}

$date1='2018-01-09 16:14:01';
$date2='2018-01-09 17:30:04';

cal_data($date1, $date2);
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado :D