# php contar horas restantes

Tags: php

Qual a melhor maneira de calcular as horas restantes de uma data?
Exemplo:

```
$date = 2018-02-02;
$calcular_restante = ....;
```

Faltam **X** Dias e **X** horas para chegar ao dia.

Qual a melhor maneira de o fazer?

Comment: A melhor maneira é aquela que resulta no que for mais adequado para sua aplicação (ou seja, se der mais detalhes de como  isso vai ser usado, ajuda). Se forem só dias e horas, provavelmente bastaria subtrair 2 timestamps e calcular em segundos, não precisaria nem instanciar um DateTime. Se precisa de muitos campos, o _overhead_ do DateTime + Interval pode compensar.

Comment: @Bacco creio que sua resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195690/3635 provavelmente já cobre a necessidade, bastaria apenas modificar um ou outro texto. O formato do tempo para Unix-time seria apenas um detalhe simples e fácil de ajustar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na parte "notas" eu até dei a solução já, se quiser formato de data textual. Bem observado, creio que realmente resolve. .

Comment: @Bacco marquei como dup. Mitchel se tiver mais algum detalhe ou algo especifico cujo [a resposta do Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195690/3635) não cobre/resolve por favor informe que irei providenciar a reabertura.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ou, conforme for eu acrescento detalhes na original, assim fica mais organizado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar as classes [**DateTime**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php) e [**DateInterval**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php).

A classe [**DateTime**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php) possui um método (`DateTime::diff`) que, passando outra data, ele vai calcular a diferença e vai te retornar um [**DateInterval**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php) informando o quanto falta em anos, meses, dias, horas, minutos e segundos para chegar a uma determinada nada.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

$dataInicial = new DateTime();
$dataFinal = new DateTime("2018-07-13");

$diferenca = $dataInicial->diff($dataFinal);

echo sprintf("Faltam %d anos, %d meses, %d dias, %d horas, %d minutos e %s segundos para {$dataFinal->format('d/m/Y')}",
    $diferenca->y,
    $diferenca->m,
    $diferenca->d,
    $diferenca->h,
    $diferenca->m,
    $diferenca->s);
```

[**Demonstração**](https://ideone.com/gnL1QM)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
tente desta forma, você pode ir adaptando o código para chegar ao resultado desejado.

```
<?php

$data1 = new DateTime();
$data2 = new DateTime('2018-08-20 00:00:00');

echo $data2->diff($data1)->format('Faltam %Y Anos %m Mês, %d dias e %h horas %i minutos');
```