# Obter tempo transcorrido de uma string

Tags: c#, .net, json, string, datetime

Queria calcular o tempo de agora com o que eu recebo de uma string como essa:

```
2016-04-16T15:55:53Z
```

Porém o tempo é três horas superior ao nosso fuso, queria alguma saída do tipo:

```
Já se decorreu 0 horas, 0 minutos e 0 segundos...
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer. Há alguma dificuldade específica ou você só não sabe como converter a *string* para `datetime`. Só um detalhe, isto é uma data completa comum, não é um tempo decorrido.

Comment: Só quero comparar o tempo de agora DateTime.Now com esse que recebo, e retornar o tempo decorrido entre os 2 como mencionei no texto.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo. Pode até aceitar a sua.

Answer (score 3):

Vou responder o que dá:

```
DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("2016-04-16T15:55:53Z")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Parse2.cs).

Se não tiver certeza que o texto tem esse formato é melhor usar o [`TryParseExact()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152900/101).

Quanto ao fuso depende de como tem essa informação, precisa estar em algum lugar. Tem várias formas de resolver isto, algumas mais corretas que outras dependendo do cenário.

Para colocar o [tempo decorrido por extenso já respondi em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82278/101).

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int hours, minutes, seconds;
            DateTime dt1,dt2;
            dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-04-16T15:55:53Z");
            dt2 = DateTime.Now;
            dt2.AddHours(3);
            seconds = (int)dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalSeconds % 60;
            minutes = (int)dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalMinutes % 60;
            hours = (int)dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalHours;
            Console.WriteLine("Ja se passaram: " + hours + " hora(s), " + minutes + " minuto(s) e " + seconds + " segundo(s)");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Não é a melhor solução mas resolveu minha questão.