# Como converter data no formato dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

Depois q publiquei minha app, comecei a receber as datas no formato americano assim:*9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM*

Como formatar para `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Tentei `convert.ToDateTime()` mais não funciona.

Comment: Seu App é de qual tipo? é WEB?

Comment: recebe como? texto? pode garantir que o formato é sempre esse? É porque vem em formato americano? Você precisa colocar detalhes do que tem e o que precisa para receber uma resposta com os detalhes corretos. Se os detalhes só terão respostas chutes.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 9):

tente o seguinte:

```
DataLabel.Text = variavelDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Para mais informações, você pode ver esta página da Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Se tiver certeza do forma, uma das formas de fazer isso seria fazer uma [`Parse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads) no formato americano:

```
DateTime.Parse(data, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Se pode falhar e quer especificar o formato pode usar o [`TryParseExact()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads):

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                            DateTimeStyles.None, out date2)
```

Desta forma se falhar poderá tratar de alguma forma. Se isso servir, mas tiver certeza que a conversão sempre vai dar certo, pode usar o `ParseExact()` que é mais simples.

Para apresentar em um formato específico pode ser usado o [`ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) na maioria dos casos. Mas existem outras opções, por isso é sempre bom conhecer toda documentação.

Se o formato não atendeu, pode estudar [todos os padrões disponíveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e ir adaptando.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/J5Trxi). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xZkS1F). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/ParseExact4.cs).

No C# 7 pode fazer mais simples:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None, out var date2) //note o var, a variável foi declarada aqui mesmo
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar o Datetime.Parse

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-05-08 04:00:00 PM").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: nenhuma conversao esta dando certo, porque o mes esta vindo no lugar do dia, "9/14/2016 12:00:00 AM", é desta forma que sempre vem.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc165448.aspx olhe este artigo...

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para complementar,

a partir do C#6 é possível formatar uma data utilizando interpolação.

```
string diaAtual = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}";
```

Mais detalhes podem ser adquiridos através deste [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

Answer (score -1):

Sei que não é a forma mais elegante, mas tente da seguinte forma:
*campo*.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Se o idioma do seu S.O for português, o formato da data sairá na formatação correta mesmo estando invertido o 'mês' (MM) com o 'dia' (dd).

Answer (score -3):

```
var data = DateTime.Parse("10/09/2018").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     ----Saída: 2018/09/10

var data = DateTime.Parse("2018/09/10").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    -----Saída: 10/09/2018
```