# Formatar Data C#

Tags: c#

Formatar Data

Recebo 2017-06-13 do banco de dados, usando o código:

```
Dia = sqlDataReader["DESCRICAO"].ToString(),
```

Gostaria de mostrar 13/06/2017, como posso fazer essa formatação?

Comment: Seu campo retorna um date ou string?

Comment: O Campo retorna uma String.

Comment: de uma olhada no [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152781/como-converter-data-no-formato-dd-mm-yyyy) que marcaram como duplicado, la você vai encontrar a resposta!

Comment: suaVariavel = DateTime.ParseExact(dataParaSerFormatada), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;