# Como colocar há quantas horas o post foi postado?

Tags: html, aplicação-web, asp

Estou com um site aqui que está *pipocando* problemas cada vez mais. Ele foi feito em ASP CLASSIC por outro programador e eu estou mais perdido que qualquer outra coisa nessa lógica bagunçada.

O problema é o seguinte: o site é um portal de notícias, no qual, conforme são realizadas todas postagens, aparece no canto há quantas horas a publicação foi relizada. O problema é que, não está mostrando essas horas.. Ele começa a contar as horas a partir do momento que o usuário (qualquer outra pessoa entra no site) entra no site, sendo assim, contando a partir das horas que o user está no portal. Segue imagem:
[image: Problema:]

```
<div class="col-xs-12 titulo-editoria p-a-0" style="border-color:@Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Cor">
       <span class="nome-categoria" style="color:@Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Cor">
                            @Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Nome
       </span>
       <span class="chapeu-topo">- HÁ @Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.DataPublicacao.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Hours HORAS</span>
</div>
```

O que poderia fazer pra solucionar isso? Agradeço!

*EDIT*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Lucas, bem vindo ao site.
Postar somente imagens dificulta um pouco a nossa ajuda. Será que você poderia postar o código ao invés da imagem?

Comment: Aproveitando, retire a parte do `.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Hours` e veja se retorna algum valor.

Comment: Lembrando também que dessa forma você possui um grande problema, pois se a pessoa acessar o site antes de ter 1 hora, sempre irá mostrar 0. Se quiser sanar esse problema, você pode [dar uma olhada nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82278/20615) e em suas respostas.

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12 titulo-editoria p-a-0" style="border-color:@Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Cor">
                            <span class="nome-categoria" style="color:@Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Cor">
                                @Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Nome
                            </span>
                            <span class="chapeu-topo">- HÁ @Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.DataPublicacao.Value.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Hours HORAS</span>
                        </div>

Comment: Ei Lucas, fico feliz que queira melhorar o post. Mas o ideal é você [edit] o post e postar essa informação lá.
Mas, o mais importante é saber o valor exato que `@Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.DataPublicacao` está retornando. Poderia postar esse valor também?

Comment: Fiz uma edição no post que mostra uma imagem de como está após a retirada do .Subtract(DateTime.Now).Hours

Comment: Pela data fala que o horário é 23/08/2017 00:00:00. Ou seja, ou foi uma grande coincidência (que duvido) ou o seu código não está salvando o horário. Você pode verificar no banco ou em outro local se a hora está sendo salva no momento da criação do post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do [DateTime.Subtract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s85h2eca(v=vs.110).aspx) você poderia inverter os valores de datas que torna seu bloco da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 titulo-editoria p-a-0" style="border-color:@Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Cor">
   <span class="nome-categoria" style="color:@Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Cor">
                        @Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.TbCategoria.Nome
   </span>
   <span class="chapeu-topo">- HÁ @(DateTime.Now.Subtract(Model.FK_NoticiaTopo2.DataPublicacao.Value).Hours) HORAS</span>
```