# Como converter 39 horas para o tipo 'TIME'

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, conversão, decimal

Para realizar certa tarefa, contabilizo em meu sistema o tempo gasto da respectiva tarefa.

Hoje me deparei com o seguinte:

> ```
> Data Inicial: 17/12/2018 16:49:14
> Data Final: 19/12/2018 08:02:58
>
> totalizando: 2362,29 minutos.
>
> Converto para decimal: (2362,29 / 60) = 39,3716
> ```

Porém preciso converter esse valor (39,3716) para o formato `TIME`

Porém, segundo documentação [hora (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

O intervalo permitido é de: `00:00:00.0000000 a 23:59:59.9999999`

Teria algum outro modo de representar esse valor com o tipo `TIME`?

Obs: Sei que, o valor 39,3716, representa 39 horas e 50 minutos, porém preciso que a coluna seja do time `TIME`, caso contrario, poderia definir a coluna como  `VARCHAR` e apresentar o valor 39:50.

Comment: Por que a coluna precisa ser `TIME`? Um `TIME` representa um horário (um momento específico do dia), e o valor que você tem é uma duração (uma quantidade de tempo, sem qualquer relação com um momento específico) - na verdade é somente um número, então por que não guardá-lo como número, e só convertê-lo para algum formato específico quando for mostrá-lo? Dependendo, é até mais fácil guardar o valor numérico e fazer esta conversão no frontend, por exemplo. Até porque `TIME` não aceita valores maiores que 23:59, então não tem como usá-lo neste caso...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, o tipo `TIME` foi criado para indicar um ponto específico na linha do tempo, não para indicar intervalos de tempo que é o que deseja. Esse requisito "preciso converter esse valor (39,3716) para o formato TIME" parte de uma premissa errada, é como querer medir quanto tem de leite em metros.

A forma correta para armazenar um intervalo de tempo é colocar a quantidade de unidade de tempo. Provavelmente o mais adequado é a quantidade de segundos, mas pode ter uma precisão maior ou menor, desde que você saiba qual é ela sempre, pode ser só minutos, por exemplo.

O .NET possui um tipo mais especializado que lida melhor com isso para você, é o [`Timespan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Infelizmente os bancos de dados não costumam ter um tipo assim, então precisa controlar isso na mão.

Armazenar é diferente de apresentar. Muitas pessoas não entendem isso. Você pode apresentar como quiser, pode até pegar essa unidade de tempo contida no intervalo e apresentar como se fosse um horário. Isso está errado. Dizer que "a duração é de 39 horas e 50 minutos" é correto, já dizer "a duração é 39:50" não é, essa notação é de horário e não tempo decorrido, mas se quiser pode fazê-lo, claro. Tem uma [pergunta que fala sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82278/101).

De qualquer forma como a duração cabe cálculos, o correto é armazená-la como um número e não como um texto. Eu iria de `BIGINT` ou equivalente no seu SGDB para guardar os segundos decorridos neste intervalo. Para a apresentação eu criaria funções que faz a conversão, algo parecido pode ser visto no *link* acima, seria só adaptar.

Eu sei, você provavelmente vai querer insistir que o jeito que está pensando está bom, mas não é o correto. As pessoas aprendem errado e trabalham com o erro por tanto tempo que fica até difícil compreender e assimilar o certo.

Ainda bem que o `TIME` não aceita o valor que deseja, se aceitasse provavelmente usaria errado sem perceber, caindo naquilo que eu falo sempre:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Fora isso eu não consigo imaginar porque 39,37 é o mesmo que 39 horas e 50 minutos. `.37` é algo pouco acima de 1/3, portanto deveria ser pouco mais que 20 minutos quando falamos de uma hora.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: vamos fazer uma vaquinha pra vc trocar seu carro kkkkk

Comment: Gostei desta foto , muitas vezes é assim , "mastárodando" ...